# How to calculate the latitude and longitude from two rows in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im trying to calculate the distance of two locations from the same table and see which is the closest.

| User | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 51.102451 | -1.190125 |
| B | 51.189029 | -1.527812 |
| C | 51.259916 | -1.069599 |
| D | 51.372573 | -0.292285 |
| E | 51.382740 | -0.506593 |
| F | 51.408738 | -0.537006 |

This is my query:

```
with group_A as 
(
select
a.user
,LATITUDE
,LONGITUDE
from Table a
left join table b
)
,
group_B as
(
select
a.user
,LATITUDE
,LONGITUDE
from Table a
left join table b
) 
select 
a.user as user_1
,b.user as user_2
,haversine(a.LATITUDE, a.LONGITUDE,b.LATITUDE,b.LONGITUDE)as Distance
from group_A a
join group_B
```

Ive tried CTE, subqueries but Im not getting anything.

The Output that I would like is the following:

| User_1 | User_2 | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10.000 |
| B | D | 345.00 |
| D | E | 9000.00 |
| C | A | 4.523 |
| E | F | 93.000 |
| F | A | 1045.00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a cross join approach with the help of `LIMIT`:

```sql
SELECT a.User, b.User,
       HAVERSINE(a.LATITUDE, a.LONGITUDE, b.LATITUDE, b.LONGITUDE) AS Distance
FROM yourTable a
CROSS JOIN yourTable b
WHERE a.User < b.User
ORDER BY 3
LIMIT 1;
```